Hosting strategies for python django rest api very light weight applications in production environment?
I am currently hosting python web services on apache server with mod_wsgi in daemon mode.
Every thing is fine until, I have added a new virtualhost or changed existing virtualhost becuase when I have changed existing virtualhost or added new virtualhost the apache server will not going to recognize it directly without reloading or restarting.
So when I do graceful restart or reload of apache server to recognize new configuration all other currently requests processing daemons of mod_wsgi getting terminated forcefully as graceful is not supported by managed process of apache server where as mod_wsgi is managed process.
So, when I am changing configuration of one python web services I am facing downtime as well forceful termination of other ongoing requests.
So, the above situation is not good in production environment.
At same time I want to host more no.of like around more than 200 and less than 300 very light weight python django web services
I am currently following the apache server + mod_wsgi in daemon mode in development environment but I know that it is not good or suitable for production environment as I cannot afford the downtime of other ongoing requests.
I want to know is there any another hosting strategies in which the above solutions will be resolved and also I want to deploy a large no.of very lightweight python django applications in production environment.
I know there will be strategies with containers and containers orchestration platforms but I want to know is there anything without containers?
Thankyou for your time.

Decent question, but more something for http://serverfault.com.

Wanting to host 100s of app instances without using containers is certainly possible, but it won't be less work than just using containers. You're looking at a setup akin to using scripts to automate your triggers, leverage Terraform for provisioning VMs, Ansible to deploy, and you can use load balancers to in combination with the above to do rolling restarts such that new requests only get routed to newest-config'd server instances (and the servers that are still processing requests will get re-config'd after their request queue is empty).
